# compress large ranges into shorter ranges in python while maintaining the labels

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, python-2.7, tuples

My code reads a sequence of predictions and converts them into tuples (e.g.
 `[start,end,label]`) based on majority %age(>x) as follows:

```
Sample_predictions = [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]
```

Actual prediction values are [here](https://text-share.com/view/e44e215e#K1um5uWHnOrvQo7I0FhFPqqsecFjXMZQ).

The top few rows of current output looks like :

```
(0.0, 1.3931972789115648, 'not-music')
(1.3931972789115648, 2.7863945578231295, 'not-music')
(2.7863945578231295, 4.179591836734694, 'not-music')
(4.179591836734694, 5.572789115646259, 'not-music')
(5.572789115646259, 6.965986394557823, 'not-music')
(6.965986394557823, 8.359183673469389, 'not-music')
(8.359183673469389, 9.752380952380953, 'not-music')
(9.752380952380953, 11.145578231292518, 'not-music')
(11.145578231292518, 12.538775510204083, 'not-music')
(12.538775510204083, 13.931972789115646, 'not-music')
(13.931972789115646, 15.32517006802721, 'not-music')
(15.32517006802721, 16.718367346938777, 'not-music')
(16.718367346938777, 18.11156462585034, 'not-music')
(18.11156462585034, 19.504761904761907, 'not-music')
(19.504761904761907, 20.89795918367347, 'not-music')
(20.89795918367347, 22.291156462585036, 'not-music')
(22.291156462585036, 23.6843537414966, 'not-music')
(23.6843537414966, 25.077551020408166, 'not-music')
(25.077551020408166, 26.470748299319727, 'not-music')
(26.470748299319727, 27.86394557823129, 'not-music')
(27.86394557823129, 29.257142857142856, 'not-music')
(29.257142857142856, 30.65034013605442, 'not-music')
(30.65034013605442, 32.04353741496599, 'music')
(32.04353741496599, 33.436734693877554, 'music')
(33.436734693877554, 34.82993197278912, 'music')
```

## ISSUE:

How do I consolidate this output so that it is as realistic as possible?

For example, a human would have simply said ,

```
 0, 30.65, 'not-music'  
 30.65, 34.82, 'music
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add up the parts that fit:

```
tups = [(0.0, 1.3931972789115648, 'not-music')                  ,
        (1.3931972789115648, 2.7863945578231295, 'not-music')   ,
        (2.7863945578231295, 4.179591836734694, 'not-music')    ,
        (4.179591836734694, 5.572789115646259, 'not-music')     ,
        (5.572789115646259, 6.965986394557823, 'not-music')     ,
        (6.965986394557823, 8.359183673469389, 'not-music')     ,
        (8.359183673469389, 9.752380952380953, 'not-music')     ,
        (9.752380952380953, 11.145578231292518, 'not-music')    ,
        (11.145578231292518, 12.538775510204083, 'not-music')   ,
        (12.538775510204083, 13.931972789115646, 'not-music')   ,
        (13.931972789115646, 15.32517006802721, 'not-music')    ,
        (15.32517006802721, 16.718367346938777, 'not-music')    ,
        (16.718367346938777, 18.11156462585034, 'not-music')    ,
        (18.11156462585034, 19.504761904761907, 'not-music')    ,
        (19.504761904761907, 20.89795918367347, 'not-music')    ,
        (20.89795918367347, 22.291156462585036, 'not-music')    ,
        (22.291156462585036, 23.6843537414966, 'not-music')     ,
        (23.6843537414966, 25.077551020408166, 'not-music')     ,
        (25.077551020408166, 26.470748299319727, 'not-music')   ,
        (26.470748299319727, 27.86394557823129, 'not-music')    ,
        (27.86394557823129, 29.257142857142856, 'not-music')    ,
        (29.257142857142856, 30.65034013605442, 'not-music')    ,
        (30.65034013605442, 32.04353741496599, 'music')         ,
        (32.04353741496599, 33.436734693877554, 'music')        ,
        (33.436734693877554, 34.82993197278912, 'music')]

curr = None     # current listed tuple that we accumulate
consol = []     # consolidated list
for t in tups:
    if curr==None:
        curr = list(t)
        continue

    if t[0] == curr[1] and t[2] == curr[2]:        # same, add up
        curr[1] = t[1]
    else:
        consol.append(curr)       # different, remember, use next
        curr = list(t)
        t = []

consol.append(curr)

print(consol)
```

Output:

```
[[0.0, 30.65034013605442, 'not-music'], 
 [30.65034013605442, 34.82993197278912, 'music']]
```

Comment: very elegant solution Sir!

Comment: if I replaced predictions with a test case such as: 
`predictions = [0]*60 + [1]* 60`
the program is returning 
`[0.0, 1.3931972789115648, 'not-music']
` alone. 
it is not outputting  the second half of the answers which should be 
`[1.39xxx , 2.78639455782, 'music]`

Comment: @DJ_Stuffy_K `predictions = [0]*60 + [1]* 61` works and gives both outputs - probably some condition < <=  etc not quite right in your code - what happens if `rate` is == 60 - it is neiter in the `if` nor the `elif` .. so not handled.